# Is there a way to click all the buttons on which i clicked and dragged my mouse in tkinter

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, mouseevent

I have created a grid of buttons and I need to change the bg colour of the buttons by just clicking and dragging on it.
This is because the grid is very huge and individually clicking each button is tedious.

Comment: did you try to `bind()` events like `<B1-Motion>` or `<Enter>` ?

Comment: I am not able to find the right way to use <B1-Motion> event for my example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can bind on `<B1-Motion>` to capture events while the mouse is being dragged. Within the bound function you can use the `winfo_containing` method to determine which widget is under the cursor.

Example:

```
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()
for row in range(20):
    for column in range(20):
        f = tk.Frame(root, width=20, height=20, bd=1, relief="raised")
        f.grid(row=row, column=column, sticky="nsew")

root.grid_columnconfigure("all", weight=1)
root.grid_rowconfigure("all", weight=1)

def paint(event):
    widget = event.widget.winfo_containing(event.x_root, event.y_root)
    if widget:
        widget.configure(bg="green")

root.bind("<B1-Motion>", paint)
root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT:** I made it few hours ago but I had to do something different and meanwhile Bryan Oakley showned the same idea :) Now I know it was good idea.

But this method selects all widgets - even if you don't want it - so I added own property `selectable` and use `hasattr()` so only some widgets can be selected.

---

I use `<B1-Motion>` on `root` to run function which uses mouse position with `winfo_containing` to recognize widget and change its background.

```
import tkinter as tk

def select(event):
    widget = root.winfo_containing(event.x_root, event.y_root)
    if widget and hasattr(widget, 'selectable'):
        widget['bg'] = 'red'

root = tk.Tk()

for i in range(9):
    for e in range(9):
        b = tk.Button(root, text="X")
        b.selectable = True
        b.grid(row=e, column=i)

root.bind('<B1-Motion>', select)

l = tk.Label(root, text="Label which can't be selected")
l.grid(row=9, column=0, columnspan=9)
b = tk.Button(root, text="Button which can't be selected")
b.grid(row=10, column=0, columnspan=9)
e = tk.Entry(root)
e.insert('end', "Entry which can't be selected")
e.grid(row=11, column=0, columnspan=9)

root.mainloop()
```

[image]

Answer (score -1):

Im assuming than you looped with range() function in order to create all the gridded buttons.

In the following OOP code you can both change all in one click,
And also Hover on each color and change the color too:

## NOTE:

- Clicking on the white button will change everything to green
- Hovering on each color will change it to blue

```py
from tkinter import *


root = Tk()


def change_myself(button,color_in_hex):
    button.configure(bg = color_in_hex)


class MyButtons():
    def __init__(self,current_color,new_color,button_amount):
        super(MyButtons,self).__init__()
        self._current_color = current_color
        self._new_color = new_color
        self._button_amount = button_amount
        self._buttons_list = list(range(self._button_amount))


    @property
    def buttons_list(self):
        return self._buttons_list

    def __getitem__(self, item):
        return item

    def __setitem__(self, key, value):
        self._buttons_list = value


    def create_buttons(self):
        for a in range(self._button_amount):
            self.buttons_list[a] = Button(root,bg = self._current_color,text = 'Button Number {0}'.format(a))
            print(self.buttons_list[a])
            self.buttons_list[a].grid(row = a,column = 0)
            self.buttons_list[a].bind('<Enter>',lambda event,current_button_index = a: self._buttons_list[current_button_index].configure(bg = '#0000FF'))

        special_button = Button(root,bg = '#FFFFFF',text = 'Changer!')
        special_button.grid(row = 0,column = 1)
        special_button.bind('<Button-1>',lambda event: self.change_everything())

    def change_everything(self):
        for button in self.buttons_list:
            button.configure(bg = self._new_color)

implementation = MyButtons(current_color = '#FF0000',new_color = '#00FF00',button_amount = 10)
implementation.create_buttons()

root.mainloop()
```

Here are the results:

[image: Hovering on each button]

Comment: This doesn't address wanting to drag over a button to change its color.

Comment: What I want, considering your example is when I left click on Button Number 0 and drag my mouse till Button Number 6 and then release the mouse, all the buttons 0-6 should change color.

Comment: Hey @Bryan Oakley, I made my QA and edited my answer, please consider to check my edit and let me know your thoughts.

Comment: @kausrikrao Apologizes for the wrong answer before, please check this code now and let me know the behavior of it. :)

Comment: @JimErginbash Thanks for the answer but I wanted the bg color to change when you drag on the button and not when you hover on it. Bryan's answer solved my problem